# Set up DNS and DHCP roles on Win 2008 server. Why don't clients show up in Explorer?

Tags: windows, dhcp-server, dns-server

I disabled the DNS/DHCP on my router and activated those services on a Windows 2008 server. Everything is working fine, but when I go to browse the network none of the machines can see any other machines, whereas they could when DNS/DHCP was handled by the router. All client settings are the same.

I'm unsure what actually drives this lookup for Windows. What is it and how can I enable it in Windows 2008 DNS or DHCP?

Comment: You must enable and configure WINS for `Network Neighborhood/My Network Places/magic network thing` to function.  Which client are you using to open the  (XP/Vista/7/2003/2008)?

Comment: Ok, I do not have that configured. Would my Actiontec router be running a similar role? Not sure what you mean about the client. I'm RDP onto the server.

Comment: What about NetBIOS? How can I configure that with windows DNS?

Comment: The client would be the access point for which you are hitting "network neighborhood".  Actiontec, no.  But it's quite possible that by using the Actiontec, your clients were allowed to elect a Browser Master (in replacement for a configured WINS server), but when they had their networking stack configured by DHCP, they no longer were electing the Browser Master.  Let me look a bit further quickly and I'll post back.

Comment: Yes, client is a Win 8 machine. Should I use NetBIOS or wins? Either way, I can't figure out how to configure them. Thanks.

Comment: Look here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd894432(WS.10).aspx or look in this direction: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ZA/windows7/What-is-network-discovery  Sorry I can't provide anything explicit.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7440/discussion-between-ryan-peters-and-mbrownnyc)

Comment: Sorry Ryan. I left for the day at work.  As johnny points out below, Network Discovery is one way Windows clients learn about each other.  The later Windows clients have all sorts of magical things that they do by default to make all Windows computers on the same network play nice together (particularly look up why you "shouldn't disable IPv6").  WINS/NBT is an old magical option, but Network Discovery is really the newest magic!  So I guess you should consider that.  Read up on them all, the above links cover both options.  *poof*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check network properties on each of the workstations and see if network discovery is active? I would think that since you changed your network around, the clients may be waiting for you to specify if the new network is a home/work/public network again.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was I just had to reboot the machines, and they showed up one-by-one in the network listing. Some still had the old DNS server and others simply needed a reboot. Johnny was technically correct, as was mbrownnyc. Thank you both.